# Is __import__ function case insensitive for its from_list?

Tags: python

I am currently trying to do imports dynamically, where I try to import all classes within the .py files inside a directory. I achieved this by the use of `__import__` function with the following use.

My file structure is as follows:

```
.
├── a.py (contains A class)
├── some_class.py (contains SomeClass class)
... etc
```

However, even though the filenames are all lowercase, the import still somehow works.

```py
for file in os.listdir(CUR_DIRECTORY):
    file_full_name = os.fsdecode(file)
       if file.endswith(".py"):
           filename_wout_ext = file_full_name.split(".")[0]
           _temp = __import__(
                f"src.packages.{filename_wout_ext}", globals(), locals(), [filename_wout_ext], 0)
```

Edit:
Later I get the class by using `inspect`. However this section won't work without specifying `from_list` parameter in `__import__`

```py
for class_name, class_ref in inspect.getmembers(_temp, inspect.isclass):
    all_packages[class_ref.title] = class_ref
```

Am I doing something wrong so that it results in case insensitivity or is it a feature of the `__import__` function?

Comment: On windows file names are case insensitive, if you run the code on mac or linux it will be case sensetive

Comment: I am running this code on linux, specifically ubuntu @mousetail

Comment: Why you need to import stuff dynamically? Better way will be importing `A` class and `SomeClass` into a  `__init__.py` file and in your main py file you can do `from your_package import *` I have not seen any usecase which use `__import__` to import some class dynamically. What is the use case.